# Manage theme related custom posts

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-types

I want to manage some custom posts and custom fields that have been created by the theme I've installed. In particular I want to change the permalink they are using. There is a way to do so? For example letting WP Types to recognise already existing custom posts?

Comment: Sorry. This question is confusing. [You have _templates_](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates) that have created posts and fields?

Comment: Sorry, I mean Themes, my fault!